# Find address of mail server by email address

Tags: networking, email, internet

Suppose an e-mail address `foo@gmail.com`, everyone knows it is served by `gmail.com` site and mail client parameters can be found somewhere near that site.

Now suppose you have an address`foo@obscuremail.nou`. Can any information be obtained with just that? I.e. can mail web interface be located or can smpt-, imap- server addresses be determined?

Comment: You can find the incoming mail server by viewing the MX record for the domain.  Web interface, smtp, and even IMAP server could be anything.  (IMAP often is the same as the MX record tho).

Comment: Right, domain is `obscuremail.nou` in the above?